# VBA script closing Excel when working with specific workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, scripting

Apologies if this is too vague, but I'm running into a VBA scripting error that just seems to have appeared in the last week and I worry is related to an update pushed by corporate IT in that timeframe.

Basically, I have an Excel dashboard with VBA scripts that asks the user to specify a folder and then runs through all the files in that folder (and any sub-folder). It opens each files, then copies a bunch of data from named ranges into a table in the aggregator and then closes the file. Basically, it compiles financial forecasting and status information from a range of files into a portfolio-wide dashboard.

Worked fine last week. As I say I got an update to O365 near the end of last week, and now it seems borked. When I run it, part way through, Excel suddenly closes (all open files). If I step through the code, it does so when closing the file, using the standard `wb.close savechanges:=true` line of code (I've tried not saving, it doesn't make a difference).

However, it doesn't do this for all trackers, only some. All files were created from the same template, none seem to be notably corrupted, though I do periodically get a "Can't find project or library" error when opening some, though not consistently. The *only* difference I can see is that if I add a watch to the Workbook object variable that is used to open each file, the ones that work fine have a Type value of *Workbook/ThisWorkbook* and the ones that cause Excel to close have a Type of *Workbook/Workbook*

Any help at all greatly appreciated, thanks!

Sample code:

```
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim tbl As ListObject

    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(filePath, False, False)

    Set tbl = sht_projOverview.ListObjects("tbl_projectInfo")
    If nameExistsWb(wb, "projInfo_ProjID") Then
    'This makes the assumption that any Excel file with the named range "projInfo_projID" is a financial tracker
        tbl.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
        tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, tableColumnIndex(tbl, "Unique ID")).Value = wb.Names("projInfo_ProjID").RefersToRange(1, 1).Value 'We know theprojID field exists, so we can add that
        'Now add all the other data fields
        'BASIC INFO FIELDS
        If nameExistsWb(wb, "projInfo_Programme") Then tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, tableColumnIndex(tbl, "Programme")).Value = wb.Names("projInfo_Programme").RefersToRange(1, 1).Value
        If nameExistsWb(wb, "projInfo_Project") Then tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, tableColumnIndex(tbl, "Project")).Value = wb.Names("projInfo_Project").RefersToRange(1, 1).Value
        If nameExistsWb(wb, "projInfo_Pillar") Then tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, tableColumnIndex(tbl, "BU/Pillar")).Value = wb.Names("projInfo_Pillar").RefersToRange(1, 1).Value
        If nameExistsWb(wb, "projInfo_ITTower") Then tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, tableColumnIndex(tbl, "IT Tower")).Value = wb.Names("projInfo_ITTower").RefersToRange(1, 1).Value
        If nameExistsWb(wb, "projInfo_Status") Then tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, tableColumnIndex(tbl, "Project Status")).Value = wb.Names("projInfo_Status").RefersToRange(1, 1).Value
        If nameExistsWb(wb, "projInfo_Stage") Then tbl.DataBodyRange.Cells(tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count, tableColumnIndex(tbl, "Project Stage")).Value = wb.Names("projInfo_Stage").RefersToRange(1, 1).Value

        'This continues on, copying over a number of other fields

        importTrackerData = 1
    Else
        importTrackerData = 0
    End If
    wb.Close savechanges:=True
End Function
```

Comment: I think the key of the matter is the location of the files. My guess is that it might be a shared location or one that Office treats like a shared location. So, depending upon the connection you get different kinds of access, which results in different types of workbooks, which are treated differently. Look at how you handle the paths. Perhaps you can share that part of your code.

Comment: Please [edit] and include the code or better a [mcve] to reproduce the issue. It might be a memory issue, eg. to many files opened and not properly closed. Is it always the same file? If so does it happen to that file even if it is the only file in the folder (that means no other files will be opened before/after the file that usually causes the issue)? Force closes are in most cases bugs (you cannot solve them it's Microsoft's fault) or memory glitches. It also might be corrupted files (but I would go for that at last).

Comment: Thanks, all. The files are indeed in a shared location (a SharePoint folder with several sub-folders), but there's no rhyme or reason to which ones display the issue. It is always the same files, but they are in different sub-folders, not always the first or last, but sometimes they are.

If I rebuild the files from scratch, it seems to work fine, but it takes forever to do so, so that's not an ideal situation, and there's no guarantee that whatever went wrong wouldn't happen again.

Comment: Edited the post to contain sample code. The code in question is called from a Sub which just loops through all the files in a folder and passes the file path to the code I've included.

Comment: Further update: I tried making an offline copy of the files, still does the same. I've also tried pausing syncing of SharePoint/OneDrive, no luck.